# Accessing feed item object for customer commuity users

Tags: feeditem, chatter-feed

I'm using the feed item object in my community lwr site but my customer profile has no access for that object how can i manage to give permissions to create and view posts. But i couldn't find the feed item object anywhere in the profiles, permission sets and sharing settings.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you checked [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_pbr_profiles.htm&type=5)?